# The RecyclerView is not getting the list(response)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am trying to view a list in a RecyclerView using Kotlin. I am writing the RecyclerView id in fragment class and setting the list(response) in adapter but it is not showing in the RecyclerView. Below the code is written I am not sure how can I resolve this problem.

Project having manly a Fragment,Adapter,xml file and the model class.

**fragment_availabletender**

**This page is having RecyclerView.**

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

                <!-- Data to make available to the XML via data binding. In this case,
                     the whole ViewModel, so that we can access the LiveData,
                     click handlers, and state variables. -->
                <data>
                    <variable
                        name="viewModel"
                        type= "com.bitcomm.main.ui.home.NotificationViewModel" />
                </data>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
                        android:layout_width="93dp"
                        android:layout_height="39dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:entries="@array/array_name"
                        style="@style/spinnerItemStyle"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                        android:layout_width="93dp"
                        android:layout_height="39dp"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/spinner2"
                        android:entries="@array/array_name1"
                        style="@style/spinnerItemStyle"
                        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/spinner2" />

                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/tender_list"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="#0f3b52"
                        android:color="@color/cardview_light_background"
                        android:padding="6dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner2"
                        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                      />
                </RelativeLayout>
```

**Model Class
This class is having model**

```
            data class TenderProperty(

                val id: String,
                // used to map img_src from the JSON to imgSrcUrl in our class
                @Json(name = "img_src") val imgSrcUrl: String,
                val type: String,
                val price: Double
            )
```

**TenderViewModel
Here response is getting**

```
             private val _response = MutableLiveData<List<TenderProperty>>()

                // The external immutable LiveData for the response String
                val response: LiveData<List<TenderProperty>>
                    get() = _response

                private val _navigateToSelectedProperty = MutableLiveData<TenderProperty>()
                val navigateToSelectedProperty: LiveData<TenderProperty>
                    get() = _navigateToSelectedProperty

                // Create a Coroutine scope using a job to be able to cancel when needed
                private var viewModelJob = Job()

                // the Coroutine runs using the Main (UI) dispatcher
                private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(viewModelJob + Dispatchers.Main )

                /**
                 * Call getMarsRealEstateProperties() on init so we can display status immediately.
                 */
                init {
                    getTenderRealEstateProperties()
                }

                private fun getTenderRealEstateProperties() {

                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        // Get the Deferred object for our Retrofit request
                        var getPropertiesDeferred = TenderApi.retrofitService.getProperties()
                        try {
                            // this will run on a thread managed by Retrofit
                            val listResult = getPropertiesDeferred.await()

                            _sortByPrice.value=listResult.toList().sortedBy {it.price}
                            _sortById.value=listResult.toList().sortedBy {it.id}

                            _response.value = listResult
                            println("hii"+_response.value)
                            Log.d("class","_response.value")

                        } catch (e: Exception) {

                            _response.value = ArrayList()
                            Log.d("class","_response.value")
                        }
                    }
                }

                fun displayPropertyDetails(marsProperty: TenderProperty) {
                    _navigateToSelectedProperty.value = marsProperty
                }

               fun displayPropertyDetailsComplete() {
                    _navigateToSelectedProperty.value = null
                }
```

**ListTenderAdapter
This is Adapter class**

```
            class ListTenderAdapter( private val onClickListener: OnClickListener ) :
                ListAdapter<TenderProperty,
                        ListTenderAdapter.TenderPropertyViewHolder>(DiffCallback) {


                class TenderPropertyViewHolder(private var binding:TenderListViewBinding):
                    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
                    fun bind(tenderProperty: TenderProperty) {
                        binding.property = tenderProperty
                        // This is important, because it forces the data binding to execute immediately,
                        // which allows the RecyclerView to make the correct view size measurements
                        binding.executePendingBindings()
                    }
                }

                /**
                 * Allows the RecyclerView to determine which items have changed when the [List] of [MarsProperty]
                 * has been updated.
                 */
                companion object DiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<TenderProperty>() {
                    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: TenderProperty, newItem: TenderProperty): Boolean {
                        return oldItem === newItem
                    }

                    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: TenderProperty, newItem: TenderProperty): Boolean {
                        return oldItem.id == newItem.id
                    }
                }

                /**
                 * Create new [RecyclerView] item views (invoked by the layout manager)
                 */
                override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup,
                                                viewType: Int): TenderPropertyViewHolder {
                    return TenderPropertyViewHolder(TenderListViewBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)))
                }

                /**
                 * Replaces the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
                 */
                override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TenderPropertyViewHolder, position: Int) {
                    val tenderProperty = getItem(position)
                    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
                        onClickListener.onClick(tenderProperty)
                    }
                    holder.bind(tenderProperty)
                }

                /**
                 * Custom listener that handles clicks on [RecyclerView] items.  Passes the [MarsProperty]
                 * associated with the current item to the [onClick] function.
                 * @param clickListener lambda that will be called with the current [MarsProperty]
                 */
                class OnClickListener(val clickListener: (tenderProperty: TenderProperty) -> Unit) {
                    fun onClick(tenderProperty: TenderProperty) = clickListener(tenderProperty)
                }
            }
```

**This is the Fragment class**

```
            class TenderListFragment : Fragment() {

                private val viewModel: NotificationViewModel by lazy {
                    ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(NotificationViewModel::class.java)
                }

                override fun onCreateView(
                    inflater: LayoutInflater,
                    container: ViewGroup?,
                    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
                ): View? {

                    val binding = FragmentAvailabletenderBinding.inflate(inflater)

                    binding.lifecycleOwner = this

                    binding.viewModel = viewModel

                    binding.tenderList.addItemDecoration(MarginItemDecoration(5))

                    val adapter=binding.tenderList.adapter as ListTenderAdapter
                    adapter.submitList(viewModel.response.value)
                    binding.tenderList.adapter = ListTenderAdapter(ListTenderAdapter.OnClickListener {
                        viewModel.displayPropertyDetails(it)
                    })
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    // binding.tenderList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
                    setHasOptionsMenu(true)
                    return binding.root

                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **TenderListFragment** Class inside onCreateView Remove all below lines:

```
binding.tenderList.addItemDecoration(MarginItemDecoration(5))

                    val adapter=binding.tenderList.adapter as ListTenderAdapter
                    adapter.submitList(viewModel.response.value)
                    binding.tenderList.adapter = ListTenderAdapter(ListTenderAdapter.OnClickListener {
                        viewModel.displayPropertyDetails(it)
                    })
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Declare adapter as **global** variable inside **TenderListFragment**

```
private lateinit var adapter : ListTenderAdapter
```

And call this method from `onCreateView()`

```
private fun setupRecyclerView(){
     binding.tenderList.addItemDecoration(MarginItemDecoration(5))
     adapter = ListTenderAdapter(ListTenderAdapter.OnClickListener {
                    viewModel.displayPropertyDetails(it)
                })
     binding.tenderList.setAdapter(adapter)

}
```

Add one more method `initViewModel()` and call this from `onCreateView` after `setupRecyclerView()`.

```
private fun initViewModel(){
    viewModel.response.observe(this, Observer {
       adapter.submitList(it)
    })
}
```

Comment: Rajnish Ji, Thank You very much. Your suggestion is very helpful. Now data has been shown in My RecyclerView.

Answer (score 1):

you are not observing the change in live data. You have to observe the changes in mutable live data and pass the list into the adapter try this code after the view model and adapter has been initilaized. 
Also No need to call **notifyDataSetChanged** as list adapter computes the differences accordingly.

```
viewModel.response.observe(this, Observer {
        adapter.submitList(it)
    })
```